# Usar o que o usuário digitar (io.read) como argumento de função em Lua

Tags: lua

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function perfil(monstro)
    print(monstros.monstro.nomeM)
    print(monstros.monstro.racaM)
    print(monstros.monstro.generoM)
    print(monstros.monstro.idadeM)
    print(monstros.monstro.descM)
end
```

E esta tabela:

```
monstros = {
    Esqueleto = {nomeM = "Skeletran", racaM = "Esqueleto", generoM = "F", idadeM = "455", descM = "'Estou morta mas não o suficiente!'"},
    Zumbi = {nomeM = "Bruce Santos", racaM = "Zumbi", generoM = "M", idadeM = "19", descM = "'Prociza ter umh celbro de 17 centismotros       .'"},
    Sirena = {nomeM = "Alamellia", racaM = "Sirena", generoM = "F", idadeM = "18", descM = "'Minhas canções são as melhores! Inspirante á Cantora :-D'"},
    Ogro = {nomeM = "Crak", racaM = "Ogro", generoM = "M", idadeM = "34", descM = "'hngbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbyæ'"},
    Dragoa = {nomeM = "SUZANA", racaM = "DRAGÂO", generoM = "F", idadeM = "1367", descM = "'GOOSTO DE FLORESS VERMELHHAS'"}
}
```

Quero fazer com que o usuário use `io.read` para mudar o parâmetro `monstro` na função `perfil`.
Se houver algum outro erro no meu código, avisem! (estou ciente de que preciso usar [isso](https://theasciicode.com.ar/) para usar acentuação)

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar uma propriedade dinâmicamente, você deve utilizar o colchetes:

```
function perfil(monstro)
    print(monstros[monstro].nomeM)
    print(monstros[monstro].racaM)
    print(monstros[monstro].generoM)
    print(monstros[monstro].idadeM)
    print(monstros[monstro].descM)
end
```

Depois disso é só ler a entrada do usuário e chamar a função:

```
local resposta = io.read()
perfil(resposta)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/5sJWXJ).